# set a value as selected while move to back view in uipickerview

Tags: iphone

I am new to this Iphone application. I have an iphone application and  i have 10 view  on each view i have stored the selected value in an array

```
 [self.arrayToPass addObject:@"1"];
```

My application have back button, I need to display the selected value when a user click on the back button 
Does any one know this ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem best solved with Delegation. Have your main ViewController conform to your delegate protocol. Then the UIPickerView can call the delegate method with the value selected. In this delegate method, your ViewController can display the value selected.

Here's Apple's documentation on delegation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html